# Cakephp 1.3 form data

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-1.3

I'm fairly new to Cake but I'm a competent PHP developer. I have a problem with going back to a form and having it retain data. FYI - I inherited the site I'm working on and it's coded poorly. I'm trying to clean it up.

This is a tour booking system with a shopping cart, but it's hand built, not part of another e-commerce solution.

```
Workflow - Each line has a view
Customer adds tour to cart. (booking)
Show cart. (cart)
Add contact details (add_cust)
Review cart (review)
Enter credit card detail (card)
Thank you page (thankyou)
```

If card is declined, I need to offer the option of going back to the card view to enter the details again. But when I do a redirect, and go back, the cart is empty and there is no data on the page.

I need to create a back button in the `thankyou` view that will go back to the card view and still have all the data. I can do it by hitting the back button on the browser a couple of times but that creates another set of problems.

I've got the method in my controller to do the redirect, but beyond that, I'm not sure how to repopulate my form.

So using the method `card_back()` all it's got in it is a redirect back to card view. How do I get my data back in there?

Answer (score 0):

Check the `thankyou` action within controller and look for code that could delete a cart info from session. It is usual that after the order is complete the cart data are removed from session as they are no longer needed.

A mistake of previous developer was he didn't think of a possibility that the order creation could fail and he deletes the cart details despite this failure.

Second option is to check if there is some session used, though. If not, try to set the cart details into the session and in the `cart` action within the controller check for cart details stored in session. If they are present fill the form with that details, if not, leave blank. Then implement the cart session deletion after the order was succesfully created and stored at the server within controller's `thankyou` action...

Comment: It's all worse than I thought. It's so messed up I don't even know how to describe it.

Layers upon layers of bad code written to compensate for other bad code. I will be doing a complete site redesign anyway and scrapping every last bit of the current code so I might just break the cake model and do it myway.